# SET ANSI_NULLS at the database level VS at the table level

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have generated schema-only script for my sql server 2008 R2, here is part of it:-

```
USE [master]
GO
/****** Object:  Database [****]    Script Date: 03/25/2015 12:17:09 ******/
CREATE DATABASE [****] ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'TMS', FILENAME = N'D:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\****.mdf' , SIZE = 11264KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'TMS_log', FILENAME = N'L:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\****.ldf' , SIZE = 4672KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
GO
ALTER DATABASE [****] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100
GO
IF (1 = FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled'))
begin
EXEC [****].[dbo].[sp_fulltext_database] @action = 'enable'
end
GO
ALTER DATABASE [****] SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [****] SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [****] SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [****] SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [****] SET ARITHABORT OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [****] SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [****] SET AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS ON
GO
ALTER DATABASE [****] SET AUTO_SHRINK OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [****] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS ON
GO
ALTER DATABASE [****] SET CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [****] SET CURSOR_DEFAULT  GLOBAL
GO
ALTER DATABASE [****] SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [****] SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [****] SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [****] SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [****] SET  DISABLE_BROKER
GO
ALTER DATABASE [****] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [****] SET DATE_CORRELATION_OPTIMIZATION OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [****] SET TRUSTWORTHY OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [****] SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [****] SET PARAMETERIZATION SIMPLE
GO
ALTER DATABASE [****] SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [****] SET HONOR_BROKER_PRIORITY OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [****] SET  READ_WRITE
GO
ALTER DATABASE [****] SET RECOVERY FULL
GO
ALTER DATABASE [****] SET  MULTI_USER
GO
ALTER DATABASE [****] SET PAGE_VERIFY CHECKSUM
GO
ALTER DATABASE [****] SET DB_CHAINING OFF
GO
USE [****]
GO
/****** Object:  User [AD-ITSERVICES\TMSDB.user]    Script Date: 03/25/2015 12:17:09 ******/
CREATE USER [AD-ITSERVICES\test.user] FOR LOGIN [****\test.user] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[TechnologyTypes]    Script Date: 03/25/2015 12:17:12 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TechnologyTypes](
    [AssetTypeID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [IncludedInSearch] [bit] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_AssetType] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [AssetTypeID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [IX_AssetType] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [Name] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[TechnologyStatus]    Script Date: 03/25/2015 12:17:12 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
```

now i am confused on why i go this sentence :-

```
ALTER DATABASE [****] SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [****] SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
```

but when creating any sql table i will get :-

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
```

so what is the final result; is `ANSI_NULLS` will be equal to off or on ? from my understanding the "`SET ANSI_NULLS`" will be OFF at the database level, unless i set it ON at the table level ? is this correct ? any why i got the `ANSI_NULLs` set to off at the database level ?

Comment: You do set SET ANSI_NULLS ON before you create the table.

Comment: @Blam so why at the beginning of the script it will mention "ALTER DATABASE [****] SET ANSI_NULLS OFF", while before creating the table it will mentioned "SET ANSI_NULLS ON" ? my question is that are the differences between the two statements ?

Comment: The difference is the order.   ANSI_NULLS is not a table setting.   We cannot tell you why the script has a line.   Why do you have SET ANSI_NULLS ON twice?

Comment: @Blam as i mentioned i have generated this script using SSMS 2008 r2 i did not write it , where i right click on the DB and i chose to generate a schema only script ... so i was asking why i got SET ANSI_NULLS ON twice ??

Comment: @Blam but one of the statments is specified with alter database as follow "ALTER DATABASE [****] SET ANSI_NULLS OFF", while the other without the alter database as follow "SET ANSI_NULLS ON" ? so what is the purpose ?

Comment: You asked lot of questions.  There are three ? marks.   Pick one.  ANSI_NULLS is not a table setting.   Voting to close.